# Applying a mask for speeding up various array calculations

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, netcdf

I have a `np.ndarray` with numbers that indicate spots of interest, I am interested in the spots which have values 1 and 9.

Right now they are being extracted as such:

```
maskindex.append(np.where(extract.variables['mask'][0] == 1) or np.where(megadatalist[0].variables['mask'][0] == 9))

xval = maskindex[0][1]
yval = maskindex[0][0]
```

I need to apply these x and y values to the arrays that I am operating on, to speed things up.

I have 140 arrays that are each 734 x 1468, I need the mean, max, min, std calculated for each field. And I was hoping there was an easy way for applying the masked array to speed up the operations, right now I am simply doing it on the entire arrays as such:

```
Average_List = np.mean([megadatalist[i].variables['analysed_sst'][0] for i in range(0,Numbers_of_datasets)], axis=0)
Average_Error_List = np.mean([megadatalist[i].variables['analysis_error'][0] for i in range(0,Numbers_of_datasets)], axis=0)
Std_List     = np.std([megadatalist[i].variables['analysed_sst'][0] for i in range(0,Numbers_of_datasets)], axis=0)
Maximum_List = np.maximum.reduce([megadatalist[i].variables['analysed_sst'][0] for i in range(0,Numbers_of_datasets)])
Minimum_List = np.minimum.reduce([megadatalist[i].variables['analysed_sst'][0] for i in range(0,Numbers_of_datasets)])
```

Any ideas on how to speed things up would be highly appreciated

Comment: Yes. I am sorry, I just couldnt figure out how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have solved it partially, depending on what you're aiming for. The following code reduces an array arr to a 1d array with only the relevant indicies. You can then do the needed calculations without considering the unwanted locations

```
arr = np.array([[0,9,9,0,0,9,9,1],[9,0,1,9,0,0,0,1]])
target = [1,9] # wanted values
index = np.where(np.in1d(arr.ravel(), target).reshape(arr.shape))

no_zeros = arr[index]
```

At this stage "all you need" is to reinsert the values "no_zeros" on an array of zeroes with appropriate shape, on the indices given in "index". One way is to flatten the index array and recalculate the indices, so that they match a flattened arr array. Then use numpy.insert(np.zeroes(arr.shape),new_index,no_zeroes) and then reshaping to the appropriate shape afterwards. Reshaping is constant time in numpy. Admittedly, I have not figured out a fast numpy way to create the new_index array.

Hope it helps.